# Is heat a concern with a microwave mounted over a wall oven?

Tags: electrical

I have a microwave over the wall oven. Can’t the heat from wall oven affect the microwave oven and how much space from back of microwave to wall is needed for air flow?

Comment: Are we talking about a microwave/range hood combo over a range/oven, or a built-in microwave over a built-in oven? What make and model are the appliances in question?

Comment: Some manufacturers provide combination appliances where the microwave may be physically connected to the lower oven.  They have taken such issues into account.  If you are installing separate appliances; then you need to consult the install information for each.  You also haven't specified if they are in the same cabinet area, one on top of the other or separated by a shelf or divider.   If there is no air flow between the area, not clear you have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

#### Heat/Airflow of Microwave Oven

A microwave oven may be designed to require air flow in the back, sides, top or bottom. In general not the top (because people put stuff on top) or sides (because a microwave oven will often be placed with one side against a cabinet). So that leaves back and bottom. If you have not actually installed the microwave oven in any permanent way then just pull it out and look for air vents. But the end result is always **follow the manufacturer's instructions**. I looked into this for another question and found that many of the larger countertop microwave ovens can be converted to "built in" oven with a kit that typically holds the oven in a way that ensures proper airflow. The same ovens are often available as "built in" models - and simply come with the kit included. This is a bit different from a microwave oven/hood combination that is designed for use above a cooktop, which requires much more airflow (and typically connection to real ductwork for an exhaust fan).

End result: If the oven is designed to mount "built in" then you can rely on a correct installation to provide appropriate air flow. If it is **not** designed to mount "built in" (i.e., you simply have a countertop oven stuck on a shelf) then you need to check the manufacturer's instructions for clearance requirements.

#### Heat of Wall Oven

I have found (personal experience, KitchenAid) that at least some ovens are designed to **NOT** have much heat on the top. This is definitely in order to protect the control panel (though such designs are often not perfect, resulting in control panel failures during self-cleaning or other extended oven usage) but I suspect it is also to prevent damage to the surrounding cabinetry. In my case, I have my wall oven in a brick wall, so that really is not a concern, but for ovens installed in wood cabinets, which is quite normal, that is potentially a real problem. My oven (and I suspect others are similar) actually has a *thermal fuse* in the wiring harness on top of the oven which is designed to (and did, once) fail if too much heat escapes at the top of the oven. So as a *general* rule, you should be OK with mounting a microwave oven (or almost anything else) above a conventional wall oven. Modern ovens are very well insulated, the top is extra insulated (typically with a large either empty or insulated space behind the control panel), and many ovens have a vent in the front (e.g., right above the door) to exhaust hot air into the kitchen rather than into the cabinet.

So check the installation instructions for your microwave oven to make sure it is installed to the manufacturer's specifications and you should be OK.

Answer (score -1):

Most microwaves that are built for an over the oven installation are already protected from range heat, but you need to also consider an ability to use your range burners in an effective and safe manner. Plus good lighting.

We always recommended at least 20"-24" above the top of the range to the bottom of the microwave, but I've never really seen a clearance requirement.

Good luck

Comment: The clearance needed really depends on the type of cooking. Making an omelette and flambe mushrooms will require different distances. That probably explain the lack of clearance requirement

Comment: @Jeffrey But the question is about an oven, not range.

Comment: Ugh, good point. reading comprehension issue on my side

Answer (score -2):

The longevity of electronic components may be subject to the [Arrhenius equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation), such that a 10 K rise in temperature results in a halving of the lifetime (around 280 K absolute). A microwave oven contains electronic components.

Do you want to cook your microwave oven?